# userId gets into the document magically

Tags: meteor

This Meteor code is working fine, but I would like to ask if it is the way Meteor does things or it is a un predictable side effect that may change under some condition later.
The things is that when I do
 `DisplayCol.insert({action: 'task1', element: 'p', value: value_variable});`
Meteor also inserts the correct userId (using 2 different browsers logged in as 2 different users) which I did not explicitly included in the document.

The above line of code is inside a server side function which is called from Meteor method.

here is the relevant information;

//lib/collection.js
`DisplayCol = new Mongo.Collection('displayCol');`

//server.js

```
Meteor.publish('displayCol', function () {
  return DisplayCol.find({userId: this.userId});
});
DisplayCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  doc.userId = userId;
});
```

In the [docs](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks)  of Collection hooks > Additional notes > second bulleted paragraph says:

> userId is available to find and findOne queries that were invoked within a publish function.

But this is a collection.insert. So should I explicitly include the userId in the document or let the collection hook do its hidden magic?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no hidden magic in that code, your `before` hook is inserting the `userId` field in the document.

When you do an `insert` like this,

```
DisplayCol.insert({action: 'task1', element: 'p', value: value_variable});
```

the `doc` that your are inserting is `{ action: 'task1', element: 'p', value: value_variable }`

Because, you have this hook,

```
DisplayCol.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    doc.userId = userId;
});
```

it changes the `doc` before inserting into collection. So the above hook will change your `doc` to `{action: 'task1', element: 'p', value: value_variable, userId: 'actual-user-id' }`

This *is* the expected behaviour.

Regarding your other point in the question,

> userId is available to find and findOne queries that were invoked
>   within a publish function.

Previously `userId` parameter in the `find` and `findOne` returns `null`, so user needs to pass `userId` as a parameter as mentioned in this [comment](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks/issues/7#issuecomment-24021616). Additional notes mentions that the hack is not required any more. It has nothing to do with inserting `userId` field into the collection document.

To have a quick test, remove the `DisplayCol.before.insert` hook above, you will not see `userId` field in the newly inserted documents.

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify your doubt further, from the 4th point in the docs that you provided

> It is quite normal for userId to sometimes be unavailable to hook
>   callbacks in some circumstances. For example, if an update is fired
>   from the server with no user context, the server certainly won't be
>   able to provide any particular userId.

which means that if the document is inserted or updated on the server, there will be no user associated with the server, in that case, userId will return null.

Also you can check the source code yourself [here](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks/blob/master/collection-hooks.js). Check the `CollectionHooks.getUserId` method, it uses `Meteor.userId()` to get the `userId`.

```
CollectionHooks.getUserId = function getUserId() {
  var userId;

  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Tracker.nonreactive(function () {
      userId = Meteor.userId && Meteor.userId(); // <------- It uses Meteor.userId() to get the current user's id
    });
  }

  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    try {
      // Will throw an error unless within method call.
      // Attempt to recover gracefully by catching:
      userId = Meteor.userId && Meteor.userId(); // <------- It uses Meteor.userId() to get the current user's id 
    } catch (e) {}

    if (!userId) {
      // Get the userId if we are in a publish function.
      userId = publishUserId.get();
    }
  }

  return userId;
};
```

Comment: OK, specifically,  the userId argument in the function passed to the hook,  how does it know which userId to use?

Comment: @FredJ. It uses the current user's id. similar to `Meteor.userId()`.

Comment: @FredJ. Updated answer.